# Fatal error: Call to undefined method, in Drupal 8 database insert

Tags: php, oop, drupal, namespaces, drupal-8

```php
<?php
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection;

class <classname> extends FormBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $data = get_data(); // this just summarises getting all the data from $form_state
    $result = Connection::insert('<database-name>')
      ->fields($data)
      ->execute();
```

When the above is run by attempting to submit the form (I've left the `buildForm` method out for brevity), I get

```php
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Drupal\<module>\Form\<form-name>::getDriverClass() in <drupal-root>/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php on line 812
```

The method at 812 is `insert`:

```php
/**
 * Prepares and returns an INSERT query object.
 *
 * @param string $table
 *   The table to use for the insert statement.
 * @param array $options
 *   (optional) An array of options on the query.
 *
 * @return \Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Insert
 *   A new Insert query object.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Insert
 */
public function insert($table, array $options = array()) {
  $class = $this->getDriverClass('Insert');
  return new $class($this, $table, $options);
}
```

I'm not especially familiar with how to use object oriented techniques in PHP, so I don't know whether my problem is with my use of namespaces / the `use` keyword, or with the way that I've tried to call the `insert` method, something else relating to using external static objects, or if there's something else entirely missing.

Can anyone help me locate and fix the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You "use" the wrong Class. Replace with:

   ```
   use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;
   ```
2. Define a variable

   ```
   /**
   * @var Connection
   */
   protected $db;
   ```
3. Fill the constructor

   ```
   public function __construct(/* other stuff*/, Connection $db) {
     //stuff
     $this->db = $db;
   }
   ```
4. extend the create function

   ```
   public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
     return new static(
       //stuff
       $container->get('database')
     );
   }
   ```
5. Use it :)

   ```
   $this->db->insert()
   ```